# Is it possible to supply multiple yAxis from with data in one series

Tags: highcharts

I want to supply a single series of data for multiple y axis rather than duplicate the data and put y values in 3 separate series.

Is it possible to tell each yAxis what value to pull from a data object?

```
 data: [{
name: 'point1',
x: 123,
y0: 1,
y1: 4,
y2: 18
```

Is it possible to have the 'y' in the data object be an array with one value for each y axis?

```
data: [{
name: 'point1',
x: 123,
y: [1,4,18]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you need to use separate series. If you want have just one series in legend, use `linkedTo` option.